# Writing a shell in C, closing stdin somewhere

Tags: c, shell, pipe, system

I'm writing a shell and I seem to be closing stdin at some point, but I can't figure out where. I have poured and poured over this code, but can't find where I might be closing it.

It only gets closed when I use a pipe like so:

```
cat f2.txt | cat
```

or

```
cat < f2.txt | cat
```

or

```
cat | cat | cat
```

The lines where this code is handled is 232 through 268 and then 270 through 288

I can't seem to get the formatting right so here is the formatted code: http://pastebin.com/pe8BkVPV

I will also paste the section in question below.

Any ideas?

```
if (ct->recieve_input == 1 && ct->redirect_output == 0) { 

ptr = dll_prev(tmp) ; 
    ctmp = jval_v(ptr->val) ; 
//fprintf(stderr, "Previous->command = %s\n", ctmp->command) ; 
fflush(stdout) ; 
            fs = fork() ; 
            if (fs == 0) { 

                if (ct->tdw == 1) { /* If we are redirecting output */
                    fprintf(stderr, "ct->tdw = 1\n") ; 
                    if (dup2(ct->fd1, 1) != 1) { perror("dup2 tdw A") ; exit(1) ; } 
                    if (close(ct->fd1) < 0) { perror("c1"); exit(1); }
                } /* tdw == 1 */ 

                if (ct->tdr == 1) { /* If we are recieving input */
                    fprintf(stderr, "ct->tdr = 1\n") ; 
                    if (dup2(ct->fd0, 0) != 0) { perror("dup2 tdr A") ; exit(1) ; } 
                    if (close(ct->fd0) < 0) { perror("c0"); exit(1); }
                }

                if (dup2(ctmp->pipefd[0], 0) != 0) { 
                    perror("dup2 : 0, 0") ; 
                    exit(1) ; 
                }
                //close(ct->pipefd[1]) ;
                //close(ct->pipefd[0]) ; 
                close(ctmp->pipefd[1]) ; 
                close(ct->pipefd[1]) ; 



                status = execvp(ct->command, ct->args) ; 
                fprintf(stderr, "execvp command failed\n") ; 
                exit(1) ; 
            } 
        }


        if (ct->redirect_output == 1 && ct->recieve_input == 0) { 
            ptr = (to_exec)->blink ; 
            ctmp = jval_v(ptr->val) ; 

            ctmp->recieve_input = 1 ; 
            fflush(stdout) ; 
            fs = fork() ; 

            if (fs == 0) { 

                if (dup2(ct->pipefd[1], 1) == -1) { 
                    perror("dup2 : RD== 1:1, 1") ;
                    exit(1) ; 
                } 

                //close(ct->pipefd[0]) ; // TODO
                status = execvp(ct->command, ct->args) ; 
                fprintf(stderr, "exevp command failed\n") ; 
                exit(1) ; 
            } 
        } /* End redirect output */
```

Comment: The stdin in closed when the pipe ends.
The fgetchar() should return -1 at this point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell what you're missing is another

```
if (cc > 0) c->recieve_input = 1 ;
```

after the end of the line processing loop. You need to practice your DRY discipline (don't repeat yourself).

P.S. you've misspelled receive

Comment: Thanks, I know it's a late response but for some reason I always misspell that word. Especially when I am tired.

Turns out I was using dup2() correctly. If I remember correctly I was calling it before I called fork, which just doesn't work.